# When an app has permission to access photos library and data services - can it upload pics without my knowledge?

Tags: cellular-data

There are several file managers on the store that have permissions to access the photo library and use data services. I don't trust all that software so I would like to know if it's possible that a software with this permission uploads fotos, or music when the permission is given, to somewhere on the internet without my knowledge?

Comment: I was going to say that an app cannot enumerate the pictures in the library, only launch a picture chooser that the OS provides, but this is no longer the case with apps that do not target 7.x, and there are [third party multi-photo choosers](https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/) out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set access permission for Apps?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/how-can-i-set-access-permission-for-apps)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it would be possible. Read reviews on the app before you download for any issues others may have found. Also, if an app with the same capabilities is made by a well-known developer, it is generally "safer" to download that app, if you are worried. Finally, you could use Data Sense to see if the app is consuming more data than seems necessary.

Comment: The question is whether Microsoft would even realize such a behavior. It would be fairly simple to just start the uploads after some time has passed to avoid raising any red flags during certification.

Comment: @Thomas Good point. Microsoft reviews apps every so often, though, not just during publishing. I'm not sure what all their "review" includes, however. If the .appxupload file also allows them to view source code (and if they view it), they would most likely catch it.

Comment: From my own experience the publishing process is now so fast (usually < 12h) that I can't imaginge they'd check the source code, at least not manually. Plus you can always obfuscate your code so no one would be able to check.

Comment: @Thomas Right, I'm not saying it would happen during the publishing process; I have had Microsoft contact me weeks after an app was published, with an issue they found *while using it*. True. I'll edit my answer to the more dismal reality. :|

Answer (score 0):

There are several apps that try to automatically upload your photos:

- OneDrive: currently tries to catch you with an additional 15GB if you allow it to upload your photos and videos
- BitTorrent Sync: As an option, has to be switched on
- Dropbox: As an option, has to be switched on

Probably other files-in-the-cloud-apps will also have such features.

Comment: All of the apps you mentioned are a user's choice, though. the OP said "without my knowledge."